# SetWindowsHookEx HOOKPROC undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, hook, setwindowshookex

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK CallNext(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void COwnQuerDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
  HMODULE hDll;
  FARPROC cbtProcAddr;
  hDll = GetModuleHandle("WS2_32.dll");
  cbtProcAddr = GetProcAddress(hDll, "inet_addr");
  HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT,CallNext,hDll,0);
}
```

why it says "undeclared identifier"  I don't understand!?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Michael Burr `Error 1 error C2065: 'CallNext' : undeclared identifier d:\cprogramming\.......`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't declare `hDll` and/or `cbtProcAddr` properly - if they are not declared as members of the COwnQuerDlg class, you have to declare them inside the method just like you did it with `hook`.

Comment: yeah am declaring them inside the button method.